# Protocol extension method not called when cast to protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

```
protocol StateManager : class {
    func predicate(filterTag: String?) -> NSPredicate?
}

extension StateManager {
    func predicate(filterTag: String?) -> NSPredicate?
    {
        print("StateManager.predicate(\(filterTag!))")
        return nil
    }
}

class StateMachine<T, S, E> : StateManager {
}

class A : StateManager {
    func predicate(filterTag: String?) -> NSPredicate?
    {
        print("concrete A.predicate(\(filterTag!))")
        return NSPredicate(value: true)
    }
}

class B : StateManager {
    func predicate(filterTag: String?) -> NSPredicate?
    {
        print("concrete B.predicate(\(filterTag!))")
        return NSPredicate(value: false)
    }
}

extension StateManager where Self : StateMachine<String, String, String> {
    //FIXME: Refactor to use an enum vs. String?
    func predicate(filterTag: String?) -> NSPredicate?
    {
        print("StateMachine<String, String, String>.predicate(\(filterTag!))")
        return NSPredicate(value: true)
    }
}

extension StateManager where Self : StateMachine<Int, Int, Int> {
    //FIXME: Refactor to use an enum vs. String?
    func predicate(filterTag: String?) -> NSPredicate?
    {
        print("StateMachine<Int, Int, Int>.predicate(\(filterTag!))")
        return NSPredicate(value: false)
    }
}

example("Call via concrete type") {
    let intState: StateMachine<Int, Int, Int> = StateMachine<Int, Int, Int>()
    let strState: StateMachine<String, String, String> = StateMachine<String, String, String>()
    let a: A = A()
    let b: B = B()

    intState.predicate(filterTag: "intState")
    strState.predicate(filterTag: "strState")
    a.predicate(filterTag: "A")
    b.predicate(filterTag: "B")
}

example("Call via protocol type") {
    let intState: StateMachine<Int, Int, Int> = StateMachine<Int, Int, Int>()
    let strState: StateMachine<String, String, String> = StateMachine<String, String, String>()
    let a: A = A()
    let b: B = B()

    let intProtocol = intState as StateManager
    let strProtocol = strState as StateManager
    intProtocol.predicate(filterTag: "intProtocol")
    strProtocol.predicate(filterTag: "strProtocol")

    let aProtocol = a as StateManager
    let bProtocol = b as StateManager
    aProtocol.predicate(filterTag: "aProtocol")
    bProtocol.predicate(filterTag: "bProtocol")
}
```

The output is

```
--- Call via concrete type example ---
StateMachine<Int, Int, Int>.predicate(intState)
StateMachine<String, String, String>.predicate(strState)
concrete A.predicate(A)
concrete B.predicate(B)

--- Call via protocol type example ---
StateManager.predicate(intProtocol)
StateManager.predicate(strProtocol)
concrete A.predicate(aProtocol)
concrete B.predicate(bProtocol)
```

I see why A & B instances always call the concrete methods even when cast to `StateManager`, but why is the result different if I define extension methods of `StateManager` on the `StateMachine` instances?  Does `Self` get cast to `StateManager` thereby cutting off the most-specific version of the `predicate()` for `StateMachine<Int, Int, Int>` & `StateMachine<String, String, String>`?

Basically I want the `StateMachine<Int, Int, Int>` & `StateMachine<String, String, String>` generic types to have their own implementation of `predicate()` and when I cast either generic type to `StateManager`, I want the `predicate()` on the generic type to execute (not the default `StateManager` implementation.  The results should be the same as exeucting `predicate()` via casting the `A` & `B` classes to `StateManager`

```
--- Call via protocol type example ---
(StateMachine<Int, Int, Int> as StateManager).predicate() 
-calls-> StateMachine<Int, Int, Int>.predicate(intState)

(StateMachine<String, String, String> as StateManager).predicate() 
-calls-> StateMachine<String, String, String>.predicate(strState)
concrete A.predicate(aProtocol)
concrete B.predicate(bProtocol)
```

Is there a way to do this, or can I not use protocol extension methods for this?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49816045/is-there-a-way-to-constrain-self-to-a-generic-type

Comment: Basically I want a generic type that implements a protocol to have a different protocol extension method for each specific type `StateMachine<Int>` should have its own implementation of `predicate()` and `StateMachine<String>` will have another implementation of `predicate()`